# How to make a fixed navbar and search bar when the user scrolls?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to design an application has a navbar and underneath the navbar is a `input` search field. I tried using `fixed-top` but it ended up hiding the search field. I was thinking about having the `fixed-top` also in the input field as a class, but when I do that it hides some of the content. So I am trying to find the best way to do this without hiding the contents below.

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html xml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="icon" href="../../../../favicon.ico">
<title>Dashboard Temple for Bootstrap</title>
<!-- <link href="dashboard_static/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
<link href="css/rest.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header nav-logo">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <img alt="Logo"
                    src="img/logo.png" id="Logo">
                </a> <label id="nav-name">Taddm Assistant</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid">

        <main role="main" class="col-md-8 ml-sm-auto col-lg-12 pt-3 px-4">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-md-3 ml-auto">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>AppCode</th>
                    <th>Acronym</th>
                    <th>AppName</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>View</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody id="myTable">
                <tr th:each="ary2 : ${ary2}">
                    <td th:text="${ary2.dtoAppCode}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${ary2.dtoAcro}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${ary2.dtoAppName}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${ary2.dtoGpStatus}"></td>
                    <td><a th:href="@{/findOne/(appcode=${ary2.dtoAppCode})}"
                        class="btn btn-primary eBtn">View</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>



        </main>
        <!-- </div>-->
    </div>

    <div class="myForm">
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
            aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Update or
                            Create</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                            aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-form-label">Application Name:</label> <input
                                type="text" class="form-control" id="displayAppName"
                                name="displayAppName" value="" readonly /> <label
                                class="col-form-label">Application Code:</label> <input
                                type="text" class="form-control" id="appcode" name="appcode"
                                value="" readonly /> <label class="col-form-label">Status:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="status" name="status"
                                value="" readonly />

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <a href="/edit" id="modalCreateBtn"> <input type="submit"
                            class="btn btn btn-primary modal-create" id="createBtn"
                            value="Create" /></a>

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
                            id="dashboardCloseModal" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="dashboard_static/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/feather-icons/dist/feather.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dashboard_static/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: iirc, bootstrap already has some css/js for sticky headers on scroll

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at Bootstrap's sticky headers or you could follow that guide from w3school : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_sticky.asp

Answer (score 0):

What if you set a height to the nav, then you add a margin to the content.

```
nav.navbar{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}
.container-fluid{
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap then this will work.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">

  </div>
</nav>
```

Bootstraps navbar doc [check more navbars here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/components/#navbar)

**Thank you**